# Vue watch nested object and each prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, watch

I have a nested object that I want to be watched.
This is the code:

```
watch: {
        'input.source.location': {
            handler: () => {
                console.log("locations");
            }
        },
        'input': {
            handler: () => {
                console.log("all the rest");
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

By changing the `location` prop, I want that only "locations" will be printed. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is the correct answer but this would work. I don't know if vue has any arguments that would directly support your case without using in if statement.

```
watch: {
        'input.source.location': {
            handler: () => {
                console.log("locations");
            }
        },
        'input': {
            handler: (newVal) => {
                if(newVal.source.location) return;
                console.log("all the rest");
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

-OR-

```
watch: {
        'input': {
            handler: (newVal) => {
                if(newVal.source.location) console.log("locations");
                else console.log("all the rest");
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

Comment: It will not work. The newVal object will contain the nested props event if they were not updated.